# 4-variable inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that for positive $a,b,c,d$
$$\prod_{cyc}(b+c+d-2a) \le abcd$$

By taking the fourth root, both sides are less than $\frac{a+b+c+d}{4}$.

A common technique used when this happens is to subtract the expression from both sides in the original inequality, do some algebra and hopefully arrive at the result, but I can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Let $ S =  \sum a$ and expand out $ \prod ( S - 3a) $. Bear in mind that $S^4 - S^3 \sum (3a) = -2 S^4$. Then either compare terms, or AM-GM your way out.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong.

Try $c=d\rightarrow0^+$ and $a=b=1$.